# How can I put a web site into a mobile native application?

Tags: android, angular, mobile, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

First, I have a web app made with angular + angular material that looks like a mobile app, now I "ported" this webapp to a native mobile app using capacitor + cordova plugins and works fine, all the features work fine.

My deployment proces is:

Build angular app, sync to android, build android and then publish in play store (same for ios), it works, but, every time I make a change to my web app, I have to repeat this process and you know, the user has to download the new version of the app, install, and use, I would like to avoid this.

Since my app is web, located on a site (It can be accesses via web too) I would like to know if there is something that inside my webview opens the url of my site (without exiting the app, I tried making a redirection but it opens a web browser), so, the end user won't have to download the new version of the app every time I make a change and I won't have to upload the build to play store and app store.

I know that it can be done because my bank app does something like this but I don't know how to do it or how to search for it

How can I achieve this?

Thanks and sorry for my english, I hope I have explained what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

[Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) is the framework that would fit your use case. You can build apps in angular and ionic wraps it in a webview of native android apps. If you need to access native android feature, you can install capacitor lib too along with ionic. [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/getting-started) is a library to interact with mobile's api (IOS and Android) with javascript.

Anoter approach to build native android apps with JS would be reactnative. It is different from ionic. You would have to be familiar with react sytax to get statrted easily. React native is not a webview app rather it is compiled to native platform code.

Look into flutter too. It uses dart but apps perform faster made with flutter and it can build both for android and IOS with same codebase

**CONCLUSION**

If you want to stay in angular code, go with **IONIC**

Comment: Thanks but ionic won't work for me because every change I make to the code I will have to recompile and upload to app store and play store... I would like to avoid uploading the app in every change I make

Comment: You would wanna go for PWA using angular

Comment: My app is already PWA, I will check the update feature

Answer (score 1):

"Live updates" are one way to solve this.  Live updates allow you to send patches to your app and actually change the app code to some extent without going through app store review.  Big updates will still have to go through app store review, but you can make lots of little updates "live" by using a live update service.

You can do live updates with Ionic.  Ionic is open-source, but the live updates are part of the Ionic team's [Appflow](https://ionic.io/appflow) package, which is a paid service.  Pricing currently starts at $499/month for 25,000 updates.

In this same space, there's [Capgo](https://capgo.app/), which is cheaper and works with Capacitor in general (does not require Ionic).

More info: [Long discussion on this topic in the capacitor-community github repo](https://github.com/capacitor-community/proposals/issues/43)